# Allure server is generating 2 reports - Cucumber and Surefire Suite

Tags: java, automation, cucumber

I'm running WEB automation with the maven command, Ex: mvn clean install .... tag and etc..

So far ok, no problems, but when I run the Allure server to see the report, it is doubling the test values.

1. It is the feature file with the scenarios.

The 2. It's the surefire suite.

How can I prevent surefire suite from being generated?

Remove the maven sufire

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.